# Limit attempt exceeded login with Java servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm using tomcat and I'm trying to build a login system that blocks an user after attempting to login for **3 times**. It all seems to be working fine.

The only problem is that when the user fails all the 3 attempts and get blocked, even if I try to login with another account with the right credentials, **it won't login and keeps showing me the message "You exceeded the max attempts. This account is blocked."**.

It **only** works when I restart the tomcat server. What could be wrong?

Here's my login servlet:

```
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    int totalAttempts = 3; 

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        /**
         *  verifies all the values inserted in database
         *  creates session and redirects accordingly to answer
         *  blocks access after 3 failed attempts
         */
         if(totalAttempts != 0){
             if(CheckUser.Validation(username, password) && !CheckUser.SelectState(username)){
                 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("username", username);

                RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("profile.jsp");
                rs.forward(request, response);

            }
            else if(CheckUser.Validation(username, password) && CheckUser.SelectState(username)) {
                String blocked = "This user is blocked";
                request.setAttribute("blocked", blocked);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);   
                return;
            } 
            else if (!CheckUser.Validation(username, password) && !CheckUser.SelectState(username)){  
                String error = "Wrong username or password. Try again.";
                request.setAttribute("error", error);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);   
                totalAttempts--;

            }   
        } 
        else {  
            String state = "Inactive";
            CheckUser.BlockUser(state, username);
            String blocked = "You exceeded the max attempts. This account is blocked.";
            request.setAttribute("blocked", blocked);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to maintain the number of attempts for each user in DB. When the login is successful, you need to reset the number of attempts for that user.

Comment: HttpServlet is single threaded. Tomcat or any J2EE container creates maximum 1 instance of this class, You can configure web.xml and specify how many instances of HttpServlet you want to initialize. Now in your case totalAttempts variable is class level. So this does not reset to 0 during each request , as you expected.. So once count of this variable exceed maximum number of failed attempts it remains like this for any future request.